# Changing ASP.Net label's text with VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, object, reference, label

I currently have a form that has a label appear when there is an error with changing your password.

Currently there is a bug that makes a message pop up even when the change is successful that says, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I'm wanting to write a test that says when the label is equal to that message to make the visibility false. I've tried:

```
If lblMsg.Text = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Then
            lblMsg.Visible = False
        End If
```

This, among other variations, have yet to work successfully for me.

Any idea on what other ways I can write this out to hide the label when that message occurs?

Comment: You need to post more code in order for people to help you.

Comment: You should find out what is causing that error and fix it. This way your code will be more maintenable. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I figured out my error. I ended up having to write an IF statement that checked the response for nulls,  i.e: If response Is Nothing OrElse response = 0 then returnString.AppendLine("Password Changed Successfully.") End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my error. I ended up having to write an IF statement that checked the response for nulls, i.e:

```
If response Is Nothing OrElse response.length = 0 then
 returnString.AppendLine("Password Changed Successfully.")
 End If
```

Thanks to any and all who commented and helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (not the text cannot be null, or this would be a problem):

```
If lblMsg.Text.ToLower().Trim() = "object reference not set to an instance of an object." Then
            lblMsg.Visible = False
        End If
```

If that doesn't work, then there is a character off in the message.  Alternatively, why not figure out where the object reference error is occurring and fix that problem?

Comment: I figured out my error. I ended up having to write an IF statement that checked the response for nulls, i.e: If response Is Nothing OrElse response = 0 then returnString.AppendLine("Password Changed Successfully.") End If  Thanks for the help!